# Command line from cmd not parsed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I'm using cmd.exe on windows7 to execute a python script via this line :

```
> csv_cleaner.py ../test.csv ../oui.csv
```

The first lines of the script are :

```
import configparser, csv, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 3 :
        usage = """Usage: %s [inputfile][output file]\nThis program requires 2 \
arguments to function properly.\n[input file] is the file to clean\n[output fil\
e] is the name of the file that will be created as a result of this 
program\n"""
        print(usage % (sys.argv[0]))
else :
```

The problem is that no matter how many arguments I pass the check always fail, furthermore when I try printing any argument beyond the first I receive this error.

#### These lines were added for debug but are not in the actual program

```
File "C:\Users\comte\Desktop\csv_cleaner\csv_cleaner.py", line 3, in <module>
  print(sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`len(sys.argv)` returns 1

Comment: Please show us the error message.

Comment: Are you sure you pass 2 parameters to the script, the error not align with your script? Meanwhile, why do not use `len(sys.argv)` to check number of args?

Comment: The command line I use is in disponible above. `len()` is a good idea.

Comment: the error doesnt match your code, there is no line `print(sys.argv[2])` (anymore?)

Comment: @Jonas Clarification was added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was seemingly an artifact from an uninstalled python2 in my PATH.
Now that it is removed everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access a non-existing item of the `sys.argv` list, Python throws a IndexError exception.
Instead, if you want to check how much parameters have been passed to the cammand-line, you can use `len(sys.argv)`:

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 2 :
        usage = """Usage: %s [inputfile][output file]\nThis program requires 2 \
arguments to function properly.\n[input file] is the file to clean\n[output fil\
e] is the name of the file that will be created as a result of this 
program\n"""
        print(usage % (sys.argv[0]))
```

Comment: In the precedent version of the program the array wasn't accessed but sliced which don't coause an error, this is not the cause of the mentionned IndexError. The program was none the less modified for readability